Confusion regarding Desmos graph of an everywhere smooth analytic almost everywhere function with discontinuity at x=0
I apologize if this is a trivial question or something easy that I'm missing, but this is really throwing me for a loop. I'm trying to graph the function $f(x)=e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}}$. I have not defined it piecewise, but Desmos shows that the function is continuous at $x=0$. I have shuffled it around to make sure I'm not seeing a visual glitch, but the function seems to be continuous everywhere (according to Desmos). That shouldn't make sense. $x=0$ should cause a division by zero error. What am I not understanding here? I have attached a photo below. Note that the function graphed in the image is $f(x)=e^{-\frac {1}{(x^2+1)}}+1$ to prevent Desmos from highlighting the origin.


My guess is Desmos is plotting what it thinks is a turning point $(-1, 1)$. Obviously, the function isn't defined there.

What does Desmos show for something like $g(x) = \frac{x^2}{x}$? I'm not familiar with Desmos (but have certainly heard about it a for many years), so my initial guess is that it simply ignores removable singularities, which is easy to test for.

I plotted $x/x$ and it shows (0, undefined) when I drag a point there (shot). For $\exp(-1/x^2)$ it shows $(0,0)$, though, which must be a bug.
